# Error VS403357 when batch creating many work items in Azure DevOps using .NET API

Tags: azure-devops, migration

I'm trying to use the Azure DevOps .NET API to batch create WorkItems in a AzureDevOps repository, but when I submit the batch request, I'm getting back an error message:  "VS403357: Work items in the batch are expected to be unique, but found work item with ID -1 in more than one request."

Here's my code:

```
  public void ExecuteWorkItemMigration(int[] workItemIds, IProgress<ProgressResult> progress = null)
  {
      var wiql = "SELECT * FROM WorkItems";
      var query = new Query(_workItemStore, wiql, workItemIds);
      var workItemCollection = query.RunQuery();
      string projectName = MainSettings.AzureDevOpsSettings.ProjectName;

      List<WitBatchRequest> batchRequests = new List<WitBatchRequest>();
      foreach (WorkItemTfs tfsWorkItem in workItemCollection)
      {
          JsonPatchDocument document = CreateJsonPatchDocument(tfsWorkItem);
          string workItemType = GetWorkItemType(tfsWorkItem);
          WitBatchRequest wibr = _azureDevopsWorkItemTrackingClient.CreateWorkItemBatchRequest(projectName, workItemType,
              document, true, true);

          batchRequests.Add(wibr);
      }

      List<WitBatchResponse> results = _azureDevopsWorkItemTrackingClient.ExecuteBatchRequest(batchRequests).Result;
  }


private static JsonPatchDocument CreateJsonPatchDocument(WorkItemTfs tfsWorkItem, int id = -1)
    {
        var document = new JsonPatchDocument();
        document.Add(
            new JsonPatchOperation
            {
                Path = "/id",
                Operation = Operation.Add,
                Value = id
            });

        document.Add(
            new JsonPatchOperation
            {
                Path = "/fields/System.Title",
                Operation = Operation.Add,
                Value = tfsWorkItem.Title
            });

        if (tfsWorkItem.Fields.Contains("ReproSteps"))
            document.Add(
                new JsonPatchOperation
                {
                    Path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps",
                    Operation = Operation.Add,
                    Value = tfsWorkItem.Fields["ReproSteps"].Value
                });

    }
```

Any suggestions about what I need to do to get this working properly?
I have tried submitting different unique ID's but it doesn't seem to prevent the error from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use unique *negative* ID's for creating the WorkItem ID.

Something like this:

```
public void ExecuteWorkItemMigration(int[] workItemIds, IProgress<ProgressResult> progress = null)
    {
        var wiql = "SELECT * FROM WorkItems";
        var query = new Query(_workItemStore, wiql, workItemIds);
        var workItemCollection = query.RunQuery();
        string projectName = MainSettings.AzureDevOpsSettings.ProjectName;

        List<WitBatchRequest> batchRequests = new List<WitBatchRequest>();

        int id = -1;
        foreach (WorkItemTfs tfsWorkItem in workItemCollection)
        {
            JsonPatchDocument document = CreateJsonPatchDocument(tfsWorkItem, id--);
            string workItemType = GetWorkItemType(tfsWorkItem);
            WitBatchRequest wibr = _azureDevopsWorkItemTrackingClient.CreateWorkItemBatchRequest(projectName, workItemType,
                document, true, true);

            batchRequests.Add(wibr);
        }

        List<WitBatchResponse> results = _azureDevopsWorkItemTrackingClient.ExecuteBatchRequest(batchRequests).Result;
    }
```